# Syncing work email to phone S6

Tags: mobile-network

I have an S6. I had to change my work email password, which I also get on my phone. Now phone won't show new emails, dings at me. How do I sync them up? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the email app.
2. Tap on Inbox above your account name.
3. Tap on SETTINGS in the top right.
4. Under Accounts, tap on the account to which you need to change the password.
5. Scroll all the way down and tap the last option Server settings.

The settings that appear here include email address, user name, and most importantly, password.

After changing the password, return the the main email screen and swipe down for a refresh and sync.